# Multiple htaccess re-write rules with friendly URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

My mobile site (tiny custom CMS inspired by wordpress) has a homepage,  blog page, a news page, an about page and a contact page where `./blog` `./news` `./about` and `./contact` are actual folders. *Homepage*, *Blog* and *News* are paginated. *About* and *Contact* are single pages, no pagination.

I need htaccess rewrite rules to do the following (A) and (B). I have only made progress with (A), and the htaccess file is in the site root.

(A)

- `m.website.com/index.php?page=1` re-writes to `m.website.com`
- `m.website.com/index.php?page=2` re-writes to `m.website.com/page/2` *etc*
- `m.website.com/blog/index.php?page=1` rewrites to `m.website.com/blog`
- `m.website.com/blog/index.php?page=2` re-writes to `m.website.com/blog/page/2` *etc*
- `m.website.com/news/index.php?page=1` rewrites to `m.website.com/news`
- `m.website.com/news/index.php?page=2` re-writes to `m.website.com/news/page/2` *etc*

**Problems:**
Below is what I'm using for the above, but I only got it working for the *homepage* for now. I don't know how to combine the rules to include *blog* and *news* pages too. Also, it duplicates my links because `m.website.com` and `m.website.com/page/1` are both in use. I need to get rid of `/page/1` everywhere. Pagination should start only from page 2. I tried to get rid of it using the RedirectMatch but it didn't work so I commented it out.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) index.php?page=$1 [NC]
#RedirectMatch 301 ^/page/1/$ http://m.website.com/
```

(B)

- I already have a **permalink.php** file which accepts pretty URLs and returns their postIDs
- The read-more link for each article on the home, blog or news page will have the format `http://m.website.com/2012/03/the-post-title`
- When clicked, the htaccess will query permalink.php with the string `/2012/03/the-post-title` to get the postID, then opens `http://m.website.com/article.php?id=postID` **but** the address in the address bar will be `http://m.website.com/2012/03/the-post-title` and this shows the article in full, be it home page, blog page or news page.

**Problem:** I have been searching and I'm not exactly sure how to go about (B) above but I know it's possible. In the end, all rules for A and B will be in the same htaccess file in the site root.

Thanks

Comment: The cleanest solution would be using only a single rewrite rule which redirect all requests that are not for static resources to your PHP script which then does all the url parsing etc.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thanks. But there are 3 PHP files (index.php) for the home page, blog page and the news page having different queries and stuff. How will a single rewrite rule work then?

Comment: Route everything through another PHP file which then includes the proper file.

Comment: Thinking again, I can combine those three into one page and set a variable ("category" or so, to equal "home", "blog" and "news") and append that to the single index.php using htaccess. But that seems even more complex unless I get some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you. It looks like you have done most of it so there isn't muc to do.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /

# you do not need a rewrite for the root as you should have index.php
# as your default document and page 1 as your default page

RewriteRule ^page/1/?$                    / [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)/?$                index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

# you do not need a rewrite for blog as you should have index.php as your
# default document and page 1 as your default page

# you do not need a rewrite for news as you should have index.php as your
# default document and page 1 as your default page

RewriteRule ^(blog|news)/page/1/?$        $1 [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(blog|news)/page/(\d+)/?$    $1/index.php?page=$2 [NC,L]

######################################################################
################## ADD YOUR PERMALINK.PHP CODE HERE ##################
######################################################################
```

**UPDATE**
To effectively turn /2012/03/the-post-title into a postID you need to be able to ask your database to do that for you as it is the only thing that knows the answer. So you can either use a `RewriteMap` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbd I have never done this myself and I would advise against it. Not because I know there is a problem with it I just have a *bad* feeling about it.

The alternative and one I would champion is to just do something like this:-

```
RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/(\d{2})/([^/]+))/?$     article.php?postIdentifier=$1/$2/$3 [L]
```

Then in article.php hit the database and use the information in the postIdentifier to get the correct article.

Make sense?

Comment: Hi Baynezy, thanks! I want to test and accept this, but the above appears to solve only the (A) part of my problem. As for the B part, how do I rewrite the pretty URL permalink into a postID? If you need clarification on the problem please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Baynezy! I will try that out right now. I realized I made one error. The application is in a subfolder `./application/demo` of the main site, so it appears the RewriteBase cannot be / (or should it be?) I tried `RewriteBase /application/demo/` but all rewrites didn't work. Can you please advice me on that here, in the comments? I think this should work, will accept right after.

Comment: Well then you can prefix all the RewriteRule with application/demo e.g. `RewriteRule ^application/demo/page/(\d+)/?$                application/demo/index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: Now I have moved it to the root just to test, and Im getting 500 internal server errors. Please did you test this?

Comment: I am accepting the answer, although I still have sub-directory errors. But you have given me a lot to work with. Thanks for all your help!